# gtkmm app ignores system theme in 3.0, while OK in 2.4

Tags: themes, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I compiled a test example using `gtkmm-3.0` library and I noticed that it looks uglier than every other GTK+ app in my system, as if it ignored my system-wide theme. When I rebuilt that app against `gtkmm-2.4`, it looks OK.

The code is almost the same, discounting for the `Gtk::Application` class from `gtkmm-3.0` replaced with `Gtk::Main` from `gtkmm-2.4`.

What could be the cause of the problem? Why is my app ignoring my system theme when compiled against `gtkmm-3.0` but not when I compile it against `gtkmm-2.4`? Is it some system configuration problem? Or should I do something special in `gtkmm-3.0` to use my system theme?

I'm on Gentoo Linux if that matters.

Comment: Are other applications linked against gtkmm-3.0 displaying correctly when run from terminal?

Comment: Nope, everything I link against gtkmm-3.0 ignores the system-wide theme.

Comment: Does this theme have gtk3 settings? Themes have changed between Gtk2 and Gtk3. [ugly gtk3 theme in Arch](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116451)

Comment: Oh... So you're suggesting that gtkmm-3.0 can be linked with GTK3 and gtkmm-2.4 with GTK2, and it is the theme which doesn't work with GTK3? Hmm... Sounds plausible, but I don't know how to check that. Where are the theme settings? The theme I use is "Murrina Candy". Hmm.. but this would mean that all apps in my system are linked with GTK2 :q Which is quite odd, because I updated to GTK3 long time ago...

Comment: gtkmm3 lists gtk3 [as a dependency](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.0/sec-installation-dependencies.html.en) and it seems all Murrina themes are [gtk2 only](http://superuser.com/questions/662891/murrine-engine-on-gtk3). Theme settings are in [~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116451) or you can use [GTK_THEME](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-running.html) env for quick check.